# To access a WindowsForms Control on the correct Thread, can i use the Invoke method from the Control itself

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am processing a Queue of Controls in response to a Timer Elapsed event.
All the tutorials I've seen on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx) show something like this;

```
    string text = "abc";
    if (this.myControl.InvokeRequired)
    {
        // we are in a class that inherits from 'Form'
        this.Invoke(new MyDelegate(MyMethod), text);
    }
    else
    {
        MyMethod(text);
    }
```

I am not in a class that is a System.Windows.Form so I can't call

> this.Invoke(.....

This is how i got around not having a Form to call Invoke on;

```
    Control myControl = myQueue.Dequeue();
    if (myControl.InvokeRequired)
    {
        // Note that MyMethod takes myControl as an argument
        // and I am also using the Invoke method on myControl
        myControl.Invoke(new MyDelegate(MyMethod), myControl);
    }
    else
    {
        MyMethod(myControl);
    }
```

Are there any rules / guidelines on whether I should be calling Invoke on the Control or it's Form? What is the difference between using either of these?

Also is there anything to consider because in the delegate I am accessing the same Control whose Invoke method I am calling?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the `Control.Invoke` method; in particular the [Remarks Section - Note callout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1).  It is pretty clear that it is a thread safe call.  Take a look at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,6a42493431e5f9f2) and you will see that calling Invoke effectively finds its parent form (if it has one) and executes on that.

Comment: So calling myControl.Invoke is the same as calling theFormMyControlIsOn.Invoke. So working with myControl in the delegate that is invoked using myControl would also be fine - thanks!